# need display filter to display tcp packets of non zero payload in wireshark

Tags: wireshark

i have a pcap which contains only tcp packets. now i want to see only those packets which have non zero payload length. can someone please let me know which display filter to use ? using

```
data.len or
tcp.pdu.size
```

doesnt help. please let me know the appropriate filter. Even

```
frame.length
```

wont suffice as headers may be of different length. so some sort of filter like tcp.payload_len is required. any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is `tcp.len` which is the length of the payload. I won't be populated when the frame contains no payload.

The full list of tcp attributes you can filter on is available here: http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/t/tcp.html